# How do I execute PyBluez samples using BlueZ5 library as normal user (without sudo)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bluetooth, bluez, pybluez

System: Ubuntu 15.10 with Bluez 5.38

PyBluez with BlueZ 4 didn't have any problem with this. But since migrating to BlueZ 5 and making necessary adjustments to run the bluetooth code, I cannot run the same programs without `sudo`. Using `sudo` everything works as expected. However, if I run without sudo, the following error is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sidmeister/mymodule/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyBluez-0.22-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/bluetooth/bluez.py", line 240, in advertise_service
    protocols)
_bluetooth.error: (13, 'Permission denied')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/sidmeister/mymodule/mymodule/blue/receiver.py", line xxx, in some_function
    profiles=[bluetooth.SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE]
  File "/home/sidmeister/mymodule/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyBluez-0.22-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/bluetooth/bluez.py", line 242, in advertise_service
    raise BluetoothError (str (e))
bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: (13, 'Permission denied')
```

I understand that this stems from increased security in newer bluetooth library which is why it needs `sudo`. But, is there any special group (like `video` in case of accessing camera) that has inherent access to bluetooth so that I can make my user a member of that group and it will be able to access bluetooth without `sudo`? FYI, my user is already a member of `dialout` group and it doesn't help.

Please let me know if there is any other way I can tackle this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setcap` to set permissions on the python executable.

To install `setcap` on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libcap2-bin
```

To figure out where your python executable is:

```
which python
```

This will often be a link. You'll need to figure out the actual path of the binary. On my machine, `/usr/bin/python` is a link to `/usr/bin/python2.7`

To assign the appropriate permissions to the executable:

```
sudo setcap 'cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin+eip' <path-to-python-binary-here>
```

Related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182559

Comment: I did this. Works in 14.04 but fails in 15.10. With `sudo` it works fine. I need this to work in 15.10 without `sudo`!

Comment: From your question, it looks like you're using python 3.4, so I assume your binary would be something like `/usr/bin/python3.4` - is that correct?  Did you get an error while running `setcap` or did it just not fix the issue of having to run your python code with `sudo`?

Comment: Yes. I set permission for python3.4 and it was smooth. However, it didn't solve the permission issue. It gave out when `bluetooth._bluetooth.sdp_advertise_service` was being called inside `bluez.py` library